# Is there a way to shape the edges of an img element according to the image inside?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some buttons with an image element inside that I'm using CSS Filter to invert, but when I do, it changes the background of the img element as well, because the border is a square, and it doesn't fit around the edges of the image. Is there a way I can fix this, either by changing the element to fit around the image, or only change certain colours with CSS Filter? Any help would be appreciated.

Before:
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGPgA.png)

After:
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClP6G.png)

The desired result would be to get rid of that weird brown colour, if that's possible.

Button HTML:

```
<button class="Word button"><img class="wordImg" src="./res/Word.png" srcset="./res/Word.svg" alt=""></button>
```

CSS:

```
.wordImg {
    background-color: rgb(54, 75, 109);
}

.button {
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.inverted {
    filter: invert(100%);
}
```

JS:

```
const wordBtn = document.querySelector('.Word');
const wordImg = document.querySelector('.wordImg');

wordBtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    desktop = `${homePath}/Desktop`;
    console.log(desktop);
    wordImg.classList.toggle('inverted');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this.  Have the filter only apply to the image itself.

In your JS, I'd have inversion apply to the button itself rather than the image.

```
wordBtn.classList.toggle('inverted');
```

Also, if you are concerned about SVG support, a srcset needs to be in a source tag separate from the img tag.

Also, does your image have transparent parts for the parts that actually need transparency?

```
<style>
.wordImg 
{
    background-color: rgb(54, 75, 109);
}

.button 
{
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button.inverted img 
{    
    filter: invert(100%);
}
</style>

<!-- HTML -->
<button class="Word button">
<picture>
<source srcset="./res/Word.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />
<img class="wordImg" src="./res/Word.png" alt="" />
</picture>

</button>
```

Comment: Hi, this hasn't worked, unfortunately. I still get the same thing where the background turns a weird shade of brown.

Comment: Does the image you're using have the navy background or is that part transparent?

Comment: It's transparent.